# How to convert a .ply file to numpy array so that it could be used in python scikit-image?

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have a 3-D image in a ply file format (cloud data). I wish to perform object segmentation thus I need to somehow convert it to numpy array and feed it into segmentation algoirthms. Since I am a newbie I am not sure how exactly I can do the conversion.
Say I want to use [this algorithm](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#slic).

Comment: Check: [Plyfile](https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile)